# python regex question

Tags: python, regex

I want to match certain symbols only when they are not prefixed by specific characters. For instance, match "))))))))))" when it is not preceded by "x". Need some advices. My current expession is

```
(?<!x|X|:|=|\\1)([\|()\[\]])+
```

which does not work.

[EDIT] Rephrase my question

Comment: What exactly do you wish to accomplish?

Comment: @BoltClock, i want to match the items in the captured group like '))))))))' in 's)))))))' when they are not prefixed by the characters in the lookbehind group/

Comment: Python doesn't support forward references.

Comment: For the ')))' case, the following may do what you need, `(?x) (?<! [xX:=)]) ( [][()|]+ )`

Comment: @ar,thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.search(r"(?<![x)])\)+", text)

>>> re.search(r"(?<![x)])\)+", " hello)))))")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb75c0c98>
>>> _.group()
')))))'
>>> re.search(r"(?<![x)])\)+", " hellox)))))")
>>>
```

This makes use of the “[negative lookbehind assertion](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)”: we want as many parentheses as possible, not preceded by either "x" or ")" (the latter because otherwise, we would get the parentheses starting from the second parenthesis, preceded by the first parenthesis and therefore not an "x")

Answer (score 1):

Use complementing character class:
`'[^x\)](\)+)'`
All your specific characters which should not be prefixed will be placed with `x`, along with `)`.